# Как получить значение с input'ов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 10 input'ов:

```
<form action="method_post.php" method="post" style="width: 500px;">
    <div id="picker" style="float: right;"></div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="color1">Цвет 1:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color1" name="color1" class="colorwell" value="#eadc9a" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="color2">Цвет 2:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color2" name="color2" class="colorwell" value="#eadc9a" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="color3">Цвет 3:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color3" name="color3" class="colorwell" value="#eadc9a" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="color3">Цвет 4:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color4" name="color4" class="colorwell" value="#eadc9a" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="color3">Цвет 5:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color5" name="color5" class="colorwell" value="#eadc9a" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="color3">Цвет 6:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color6" name="color6" class="colorwell" value="#eadc9a" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="color3">Цвет 7:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color7" name="color7" class="colorwell" value="#eadc9a" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="color3">Цвет 8:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color8" name="color8" class="colorwell" value="#eadc9a" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="color3">Цвет 9:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color9" name="color9" class="colorwell" value="#eadc9a" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="color3">Цвет 10:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color10" name="color10" class="colorwell" value="#eadc9a" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

И есть скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var f = $.farbtastic('#picker');
    var p = $('#picker').css('opacity', 0.25);
    var selected;
    $('.colorwell')
    .each(function () { f.linkTo(this); })
    .focus(function() {
        if (selected) {
            $(selected).removeClass('colorwell-selected');
        }
        f.linkTo(this);
        p.css('opacity', 1);
        $(selected = this).addClass('colorwell-selected');
    });

    $('.colorwell').on('input', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Мне нужно получить значение input'a, а потом с помощью .css применить этот цвет для ссылок или фонов определенных div.

Проблема в том, что мой способ:

```
$('#color1').on('input', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Работает только когда добавляешь/удаляешь что либо в input (то есть по клику). А у меня цвет добавляется с помощью скрипта (color picker). http://ssmaker.ru/1d2e1691.jpg

http://jsfiddle.net/43htgf7p/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположу, что вам нужно вручную вызывать событие `change`. Замените в этом коде:

```
// Change linked value
$(fb.callback).each(function() {
  if (this.value && this.value != fb.color) {
    this.value = fb.color;
  }
});
```

это

```
    this.value = fb.color;
```

на это:

```
    this.value = fb.color;
    $(this).trigger('change');
```

После этого событие `change` срабатывает:

```
$('.colorwell').on('change', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в ивенте, попробуйте 'keydown'

```
$('.colorwell').on('keydown', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gdxzvkmw/

Вот список стандартных ивентов
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp
берем оттуда, к примеру, 'onclick' и пишем с jquery

```
$('.colorwell').on('click', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: changed? не, не взлетит :)

Comment: hardsky, с таким примером вообще не работает.

Comment: ок, ошибся 'change', либо 'keydown' попробуйте

Comment: @MasterAlex, ну так поправили б

Comment: @hardsky, я же говорю и 'keydown' и 'input' работает нормально только в том случае, когда я что либо прописываю в input. Но в моем случае получается так, что я вожу по графе где разные цвета и выбранный мой цвет подстраивается в input . Но в таком случае его не получается получить. ssmaker.ru/1d2e1691.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Не могу коментарием написать а не ответом((
Собственно вам уже написали что событие стоит использовать не 'input' или 'keydown'
а 'change'

```
$('.colorwell').on('change', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: Собственно я же уже тоже написал три раза что оно работает не так как нужно... http://jsfiddle.net/64pun2x0/

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как вам нужно, если можете подробней опишите какой нужен результат и функционал

Comment: зайдите вот сюда http://jsfiddle.net/64pun2x0/ , затем нажмите на первый input и через большой квадратик с права поменяйте цвет. (в консуле ни каких изменений видно не будет хотя все поменялось)

Comment: Такс, для начала скажу что ивент не работает потому что не происходит, тоесть при использовании плагина в поле input не меняется value, поехали дальше)
Я как существо ленивое я не стал ковыряться в коде плагина, а увидев что меняется стиль просто сверху навесил еще плагин для просмотра изменения атрибутов http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/
в итоге пишем 
`$('.colorwell').attrchange({
                 trackValues: true, 
                 callback: function (e) { 
                        console.log(e.newValue);
                 }      
                    });`

Comment: ну и еще не знаю на сколько офтоп для вас использование другого колорпикера, но я в своих проектах использую [colpick.js](http://colpick.com/plugin) для примера
[instavision](http://instavision.ru/editor.php) (вход через instagram)



п.с. весь код редактора написан на коленке и состоит из огромной спагетины jquery

Answer (score 0):

Mетод `linkTo` может принимать не только `DOM-элемент`, но и функцию, которая вызывается при каждом изменении. Я использовал эту возможность на вашем примере.  [Вот ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/o7dh1snb/10/)